# Tank treads wont spin on Z axis using constraint child of settings

Tags: animation, constraints

I have make tank tracks, did all the necessary with array, and curve modifiers. I also have object constraint child settings. And empty object parented to my Mesh and curve. I enter the settings as the tutorial below shows, but when I rotate the tracks on the Z axis, they do not spin.

In the comments section, some users are saying this depends on the Blender version to function, or it doesn't work maybe on a newer version.

I'm on Blender 3.4.1.

[image]
Here's the setting I have entered:

[image]

Here's the tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqfIfEx5Eb8&ab_channel=GodRayStudio

Comment: Works fine in 3.4.1 here. The only thing you would need to change to get your single track to run in the correct direction is select the curve and use R Z 180 rather than rotating the empty.

Comment: Hi there, in the tutorial at 04:45sec the tank tracks are spinning slowly, as he's rotating them on the Z axis. Mine are not spinning but remain static as I rotate them.

Comment: I managed to make them spin on the Z axis, but as the rotate they expand from each other. Something is happening to the Bezier curves.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eJPJRKra" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eJPJRKra/)

Comment: I've just done that tutorial from scratch in 3.4.1 and it works fine without any changes. First thing I've noticed is that you've built the whole thing on the Y axis rather than the X axis and you only have one Child of Constraint on each track. Did you rotate the Bezier on the Y axis rather than X after you added it? I'd suggest you start again and follow the tutorial carefully.

Comment: You're right it worked. I was making my Mesh on the X axis. Thanks!